# Error load with JS file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, rules

when I load page I also load some JS file, but i have a

> X-Content-Type-Options
>   nosniff

and my file didn't run, because it is read as text file.

> Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8

In my `.htaccess` I added this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        ############################################
        # X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
        ############################################
        # This header forces to enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter in browsers (if disabled)
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s8 ie8
        Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block" env=!ie8
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

How can I turn off this rule just for file.js?
In console :

> Loading failed for the `<script>` with source

Comment: Just get your script file delivered with a correct content-type …?

Comment: @CBroe no, i can't( I just need to cancel this rule to this file

Comment: Why not? I guess you can try to wrap this into a FilesMatch directive with a negated pattern.

Comment: @CBroe yes, it's a good solution, but i tried `<filesMatch "/js/index.php/x.js">
            Header unset X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
         </filesMatch>` but it doesn't work(

Comment: I meant it the other way around, that you add the header only when the requested file is not that particular one ... But I am not even sure how browsers are supposed to react, when you set this header for the main HTML document already, if it blocks such external resources for that document then anyway. The only correct solution here would be to fix the sh*tty setup that delivers this with the wrong content type to begin with. _Why_ can that not be changed?